# AngularJs and Laravel working with nested routes

Tags: angularjs, laravel, routes, nested

I am new to angularjs and I donl quite know how to make it work with nested routes.

In my Laravel routes file i have set up a route like `movie{id}/review{id}` and I need to make it work restfully with angular.

The problem is that I do a loop for all the movies then for all the reviews, in PHP that would be simple but with Angular I can't access the id of the movie in the reviews loop.

I have set up different controllers for movies and reviews both for Laravel and Angular.

Here is the html part for angular, note that I use modal for the create and edit forms.

```html
<div class="row" ng-app="movies" ng-controller="moviesController">

    <h2>All movies</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="movie in movies" ng-init="movId = movie.id">
        <blockquote>
            <strong class="text-center "><% movie.title %></strong>
            <p><% movie.description %></p>
            {{--<footer><% movie.review %></footer>--}}
        </blockquote>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="editMovie(movie.id)">
            Edit Movie
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="deleteMovie(movie.id)">
            Delete Movie
        </button>
        <div ng-controller="moviesReviewController">
            <div ng-repeat="movieReview in movieReviews">
                <blockquote>
                    <strong class="text-center "><% movieReview.title %></strong>
                    <p><% movieReview.body %></p>
                    <footer><% movieReview.stars %></footer>
                </blockquote>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="editMovieReview(movId, movieReview.id)">
                    Edit Movie
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="deleteMovieReview(movId, movieReview.id)">
                    Delete Movie
                </button>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="movieId = movId" data-target="#movieReviewModal">
                Post a review
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="text-center" ng-show="loading"><span class="fa fa-meh-o fa-5x fa-spin"></span></p>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moviesModal">
        Add New Movie
    </button>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here? How to access the movie id in the reviews loop? It remains accessible as `movie.id`.

Comment: Actualy how to pass it to a modal. The code pasted gives gives a movie is undifined error